# AlarmManager.setRepeating doesn't workin

Tags: android, android-intent, geolocation, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I'm making a simple app for geolocating the device.

I've made a Service called by the Main Activity that call another Service every five seconds created for get the coordinates.

The geolocating service works well, but I can't make the alarmManager.

```
intent = new Intent(this,GeoService.class);
    pi = PendingIntent.getService(this,12345,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    am = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, 0, 5*1000, pi);
```

Is it correct? Why it didn't call the service every 5 seconds?

Comment: Which is your **targetVersion**? If > 18, then it's normal. 5 seconds is a too low value. From the docs: `Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.`